# Django ViewDoesNotExist when it does

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views

I have a django app running off a Twisted service that can't resolve the views of some of the applets.

When I run the app on the Django dev server it loads fine, but when I run it off Twisted I get the error `Could not import apps.ai_stats.views. Error was: No module named aidb` when I navigate to those applets in the browser, the only issue is that the aidb.py file is absolutely located in these applet directories. My structure is as follows.

```
apps/
    ai_stats/
        __init__.py
        ai2.py
        aidb.py
        models.py
        urls.py
        views.py
    __init__.py
    manage.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    views.py
```

I can't figure out why it won't load this particular module. I have a bunch of different applets in the one app and some work with this and others don't. If there is any other information needed please let me know.

Here is my views.py file:
It calls another file named ai2.py, which then calls aidb.py.

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

import ai2


def index(request):
    # ai2.refresh_cache()
    return render_to_response('ai_stats/index.html', locals())
    # return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('apps.ai_stats.views.dashboard', kwargs={'env':ai2.PROD}))


def dashboard(request, env):
    ai2.refresh_cache()
    # env = ai2.PROD
    mf_error, mf_data, _ = ai2.AIStats().data_for_chart('most_failures', env=env)
    mc_error, mc_data, _ = ai2.AIStats().data_for_chart('most_calls', env=env)
    wp_error, wp_data, _ = ai2.AIStats().data_for_chart('worst_performing', env=env)
    error = (mf_error or '') + (mc_error or '') + (wp_error or '')
    cache_timestamp = ai2.data_cache['timestamp']
    return render_to_response('ai_stats/dashboard.html', locals())


def drill(request, env, chart):
    # env = ai2.PROD
    row_limit = int(request.GET.get('limit', 100))
    error, data, _ = ai2.AIStats().data_for_chart(chart, env=env, limit=row_limit)
    cache_timestamp = ai2.data_cache['timestamp']
    return render_to_response('ai_stats/drill_%s.html' % chart, locals())


def dash_data(request, env, chart):
    # env = ai2.PROD
    error, data, chart_type = ai2.AIStats().data_for_chart(chart, env=env, params=request.GET)
    r = render_to_response('ai_stats/%s.xml' % chart, locals())
    if chart_type == ai2.GRAPH_CHART:
        r['Content-Type'] = 'text/xml'
    return r


def pop(request, env, chart):
    pop_template = 'pop_mtd'
    if chart == 'all_mtd':
        pop_template = 'pop_all'
    ops_chart = '%s_ops' % chart
    return render_to_response('ai_stats/' + pop_template + '.html', locals())
```

Here is the full traceback:

```
Environment:


    Request Method: GET
Request URL: https://0.0.0.0/ai_stats/

Django Version: 1.3.1
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'apps.minisar',
 'apps.mock',
 'apps.actional',
 'apps.ai_stats',
 'apps.health',
 'apps.soap',
 'apps.directentry',
 'apps.toys',
 'apps.solutions']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  101.                             request.path_info)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  252.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  252.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  158.             return ResolverMatch(self.callback, args, kwargs, self.name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _get_callback
  167.             raise ViewDoesNotExist("Could not import %s. Error was: %s" % (mod_name, str(e)))

Exception Type: ViewDoesNotExist at /ai_stats/
Exception Value: Could not import apps.ai_stats.views. Error was: No module named aidb
```

Comment: `__init__.py` ? and show INSTALLED_APPS value.

Comment: It exists. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Something in `apps.ai_stats.views` is trying to import aidb. Can you show that code?

Comment: I added my views.py file. It has an import statement importing a module named ai2 which in the ai2.py file imports a function from aidb.

Comment: In that case you should show your `ai2` file as well.

Comment: That's about 677 lines.

Comment: `import >>>>>>.<<<<<ai2` the same for other imports _from current folder_.

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand what you are asking me to do.

Comment: Place dot before imported module name.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but on a whim I decided to just rename the file to aidb2 and change the import and it worked. I can't explain it at all.

Comment: @Dave2e This is a self-answer.